# Running an ASP.net Website from the root

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.net Website. the project' content is in a folder called MyWebSite.
When I run my application from Visual Web developer 2008, the browser displays the following address in the address bar:
http:   //   localhost/ MyWebSite     /Default.aspx
I want to be able to run my Website from the following address:
http://localhost/

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like it *is* running on IIS (there's no port number specified), from from a subfolder.

Comment: It's running it as a Virtual Directory

Answer (score 1):

Since it is already running on IIS, I would just change the Physical Path of the Default Website.  The original value for this field is something like below in IIS7.

`%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot`

If you change this field to the path of your MyWebSite folder than you will be able to access the web site from just http://localhost.

I have seen it recommended to change this value from its default as a means of better security.  However, I am trying to think of any drawbacks to doing this and the only one I can think of is that hard coding the path might cause some of your other development relative paths to be confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I applied this solution but when it parse my DefaulPage it displays an Error Message saying that myMasterPage.Master is not found. myMasterPage.Master is a master page that I am using in my web site.
Any further suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can go in and change the bindings settings in IIS but I advise against this. If you deploy your site as is, it should resolve correctly on a hosted server (the way you want it). Try this first and see :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new website on IIS named MyWebSite, then in Visual Studio do a File->Open->Website. Choose Local IIS and select your website.

Then it will just run it under what ever name you gave the website. In this case you could make it http://MyWebSite/

Note: running Vista and Windows 7 will need elevated privileges.